# Installing Office 2016 Without Microsoft Account

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

We have both Windows (x2) and Linux (x1) servers. Connected to these are a number of desktops and laptops (mainly Windows 7). As the hardware running Windows is now getting on there is a replacement plan in place. The first stage was to buy five Windows 10 laptops. The company has its own domain for website and e-mail services. As such they did not want to go to an Office 365 environment and brought five Office 2016 licences. Trying to install these one of our IT guys hit an immediate problem. Despite having valid product keys it wanted a Microsoft account for each install. As each employee has their own company  e-mail address our MD does not want Microsoft ones added to each laptop especially as in some areas the personnel only have a retention period of 18 – 24 months. The problem has been passed to me but searching the web and numerous forums there seems to be no solution. Has anybody been able to resolve this issue?

Comment: "Despite having valid product keys it wanted a Microsoft account for each install." - This is an optional step, assuming, you purchased retail or VLC copies of Office 2016.  Office 2016 can be activated by phone I suggest doing that, signing into a Microsoft Account is an optional feature, and can be disabled by the Administrator through a group policy.

Comment: [Office 2016 Template](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49030)

Comment: Which edition of Office 2016 is in question?